# How do I listen for a triggered event in mysql database using QT & C++?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, listener, database-trigger

I am currently developing a Quote Generator for the office where I work using C++, QT and MYSQL.  Ive mostly completed it, but I still consider myself a noob to C++ as I have not used it in years. Im using the QMYSQL driver and I have succesfully created this trigger in mysql database (CREATE TRIGGER `new_quote_added` AFTER INSERT ON `quotes`
 FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO newquotes (quoteNUM, name)
VALUES (NEW.quoteNUM, NEW.name)),

Im wondering if someone can give me some examples of how I can set up a listener to see this trigger and then publish a message to my systemtrayIcon that I have set up.  My apologies if this is super basic but as I said Im new and havent found anyone else doing quite this.  Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL has no Notify/Subscribe mechanism, unlike Postgres. So, you need to do polling on your desired table to keep track of inserts.
You may also take a look at this implementation:
https://github.com/Cyclonecode/mysql-notification
It's creating an Http server and it sends notifications over a WebSocket connection. It would not fit into every use case because of lacking security considerations.